# array of dictionary comparison

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdictionary

Here my application code output, This is my array of dictionary values array1,array2..

```
array1(
    {
    city = Glendale;
    country = US;
    st = AZ;
},
    {
    city = "Glendale Luke AFB";
    country = US;
    st = AZ;
},
    {
    city = Goodyear;
    country = US;
    st = AZ;
},
    {
    city = Phoenix;
    country = US;
    st = AZ;
}


 array2(
    {
    cont = US;
    cty = Glendale;
    sta = AZ;
},
    {
    cont = US;
    cty = Glendale;
    sta = CA;
},
    {
    cont = US;
    cty = Glendale;
    sta = CO;
},
    {
    cont = US;
    cty = Glendale;
    sta = ID;
},
    {
    cont = US;
    cty = Glendale;
    sta = KY;
},
    {
    cont = US;
    cty = Glendale;
    sta = MA;
},
    {
    cont = US;
    cty = Glendale;
    sta = MS;
},
    {
    cont = US;
    cty = Glendale;
    sta = MO;
},
    {
    cont = US;
    cty = Glendale;
    sta = NY;
},
    {
    cont = US;
    cty = Glendale;
    sta = OH;
},
    {
    cont = US;
    cty = Glendale;
    sta = OR;
},
    {
    cont = US;
    cty = Glendale;
    sta = RI;
},
    {
    cont = US;
    cty = Glendale;
    sta = SC;
},
    {
    cont = US;
    cty = Glendale;
    sta = TX;
},
    {
    cont = US;
    cty = Glendale;
    sta = UT;
},
    {
    cont = US;
    cty = Glendale;
    sta = WI;
},
    {
    cont = ZW;
    cty = Glendale;
    sta = "";
}
```

How to compare two array of dictionary value matching  the same city,state,country .Can any one please help me to solve it out?

Comment: I cant resist: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: it will always be a mystery to me, why questions that show no effort receive up votes…

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
for (id object1 in array1) 
{
    for (id object2 in array2) 
    {
     if ((object1.cty == object2.cty) && 
        (object1.cont == object2.cont) && 
        (object1. sta == object2.sta))
       {
          // do smth
       }
    }
}
```

**Keep in mind, if you have the objects of NSString you need to use `isEqualToString` instead of "==" !**

Comment: Don't you want to use `isEqualToString` instead of `==`? Since you are comparing pointer values the objects itself need to be the same, not their content.

Comment: But I have mentioned this fact already, haven't I? The point is, I don't want to do all work for the OP, it's just a hint he need ...